# Visual Studio 2015: Intellisense seems to be gone

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellisense

So today I turn on my computer and my whole Visual Studio was having issues. I had to copy my MSBuild folder from my laptop onto my desktop where the issues are, and now I can finally compile/build/load my projects. However, intellisense is now gone. I went into Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages and "Auto List Members" and "parameter information" are both checked.

When copying MSBuild, it now lives at C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild

Am I missing something?

Comment: My intellisense regularly "goes missing" - I can type something I know exists but the dropdown doesnt appear. If however I type enough of it that VS can unambiguously determine what I'm talking about then Ctrl+Space will complete it, so intellisense is half working. Restarting VS cures it for me, but it's a darn pain to have to keep doing so